# Which of these interpretations of "relatively compact" does Rudin mean in Baby Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

### 1 - Context

---

##### 1.1 - (Relative) Open and Closed Sets

In Baby Rudin, we have the following definitions:

> (Open Set) A subset of a metric space, $E\subseteq X$, is said to be "*open*" if for all $p\in E$ there exists some $r>0$ such that $N_{r}(p)\subseteq E$. (Note that in Baby Rudin, $N_{r}(p):=\{ x\in X \,|\,d(p,x)<r \}$)

> (Closed Set) A subset of a metric space, $E\subseteq X$, is said to be "*closed*" if for every $p\in X$, if $p$ is a limit point of $E$ then $p\in E$.

Then it is shown that whether or not a given set is open or closed depends on what metric space the set is embedded in. For example, $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Similarly, the set $(0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^+$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

This means the concepts of "open" and "closed" only really make sense relative to some specified space. So we introduce the notions of relative open-ness and closed-ness:

> (Relatively Open) Let $E\subseteq Y \subseteq X$. The set $E$ is said to be "*open relative to $Y$*" if for all $p\in E$ there exists some $r>0$ such that $Y\cap N_{r}(p) \subseteq E$.

> (Relatively Closed) Let $E\subseteq Y \subseteq X$. The set $E$ is said to be "*closed relative to $Y$*" if for all $p\in Y$, if $p$ is a limit point of $E$, then $p\in E$. (Note that Rudin doesn't explicitly define relative closed-ness, this is just my interpretation of what he means by it, please correct me if I am wrong)

Then, it is shown that if $E\subseteq Y \subseteq X$, then $E$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if there exists some set $G$ which is open relative to $X$ such that $E=Y\cap G$.

To interpret this result in terms of our previous example, for $(0,1)$, $G$ could be $N_{0.5}(0.5)$, and for our example of $(0,1]$, $G$ could be $[0,1]$.

##### 1.2 - Open Coverings and Compact sets

Okay, after talking about relative open-ness/closed-ness, Rudin introduces the notion of an open covering, and a compact set.

> (Open covering) By an "*open cover*" of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$ we mean a collection $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $E\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$.

> (2.32)(Compact set) A subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be "*compact*" if every open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover.

Then Rudin remarks that unlike how the open-ness and closed-ness of a set may change depending on the space the set is embedded in (e.g., the examples above), the compact-ness of a set does *not* change depending on the space the set is embedded in.

To formally state (and prove) this fact, Rudin introduces the notion of "relative compact-ness". Specifically, he says that a set $K$ is "*compact relative to $X$*" if the requirements of definition 2.32 are met. This is where my confusion arises.

### 2 - Question/Confusion

---

##### 2.1 - Nonstandard Definitions

To distinguish between some of the different ways that I think the meaning of "$K$ is relatively compact to $Y$" can be interpreted, I am going to create some definitions. I do not know if these definitions have pre-existing standard names, I am just making them up so that I can be clear with how I formulate my question.

> ($X$-Cover) Given a metric space $X$, and a set $K\subseteq X$, we define the *"$X$-cover of $K$"* to be a collection $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$ of subsets of $X$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$.

> (Open $X$-Cover) Given a metric space $X$, a set $K\subseteq X$, and an $X$-cover of $K$, say $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$, we say that $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$ is a *"Open $X$-cover of $K$"* if each $G_{\alpha}$ is open relative to $X$.

> (Relatively Open $X$-Cover) Given a metric space $X$, a set $K\subseteq X$,  an $X$-cover of $K$ (say $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$), and a metric space $Y$ such that $K\subseteq Y \subseteq X$, we say that $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$ is a "Open $X$-cover of $K$ relative to $Y$" if each $G_{\alpha}$ is open relative to $Y$.

So the main thing that I am trying to describe with these definitions is that if we have $K\subseteq Y \subseteq X$, an Open $Y$-cover of $K$ (say $\{ F_{\beta} \}$), and an Open $X$-cover of $K$ relative to $Y$ (say $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$), then all of the $F_{\beta}$ are subsets of $Y$ (and are relatively open to $Y$). But it may not be the case that all of the $G_{\alpha}$ are subsets of $Y$, we only require that they are relatively open in $Y$.

##### 2.2 - Question

So my problem is I believe there are two distinct natural interpretations of "relatively compact", and I want to know which of these is the correct one (or at least the one Rudin means). If neither of these are correct, I would be seriously grateful if someone could help guide me to understanding! Ok, here are what I think the two possible interpretations are, using the definitions I have made-up just to be precise:

> (Interpretation 1) (Relatively Compact) Given $K\subseteq Y\subseteq X$, we say that $K$ is *"relatively compact to $Y$"* if every Open $Y$-cover of $K$ has a finite subcover.

> (Interpretation 2) (Relatively Compact) Given $K\subseteq Y\subseteq X$, we say that  $K$ is *"relatively compact to $Y$"* if every Open $X$-cover of $K$ relative to $Y$ has a finite subcover.

Could someone please let me know which interpretation Rudin means? I am new to analysis and reading Rudin for the first time, and it is difficult sifting through all the definitions. I just want to make sure I am not misunderstanding something fundamental before moving onwards.

Comment: Rudin argues in the book that saying that $K$ is compact in $Y$ (or $X$ or whatever) is not necessary, as compactness has nothing to do with the "mother" space in the end.

Comment: This is slightly surprising to me that Rudin uses the word “relative” here in this way, since “relatively compact” everywhere I’ve seen it has always meant “has compact closure” (which does indeed require an ambient space)

Comment: Note Rudin does not say "relatively compact", just "compact relative to" as a temporary definition. Also, whenever he says that a set $A$ is open (or closed) relative to a set $B$, it is understood that $A\subseteq B$. This should answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of "open $X$-cover relative to $Y$" says that the sets in the $X$-cover are open relative to $Y$, but this is not a well-defined notion, since $Y\subseteq X$, not vice versa.  It would only make sense in the reverse direction - a covering of $K$ by sets in $Y$ could be defined to be "an open cover relative to $X$" if each set was open relative to $X$.

I will assume hereon out that that is what you meant.

In this case, there are in fact three possible interpretations I can see under your definition:

> **Interpretation 1**... every Open $Y$-cover of $K$ has a finite subcover.

> **Interpretation 2**... every Open $X$-cover of $K$ has a finite subcover.

> **Interpretation 3**... every Open $Y$-cover of $K$ relative to $X$ has a finite subcover.

Interpretations 1 and 2 are equivalent and are the standard definition.  To see they are equivalent, note that a set in $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if it is of the form $Y\cap U$ for some $U$ open relative to $X$.

Interpretation 3 is a *much* weaker definition and will often be vacuously true, as there are often no nonempty subsets of $Y$ that are open relative to $X$, meaning there are no open $Y$-covers relative to $X$ for any nonempty subset $K\subseteq Y$
(For a concrete example, consider $X=\mathbb R^2$, $Y\subseteq X$ a line).
I don't know of any use of Interpretation 3 under any name.

#### Remark

As discussed in the comments, the term "relatively compact" generally refers to a different concept than Rudin's notion here.

Comment: Thank you, this whole problem was caused by a fatal misunderstanding on my part of what it means for a set to be open relative to a given metric space. For some reason it was not registering that if a set S is open relative to a metric space Y, then S is necessarily a subset of Y.